# Using a variable within a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use a variable within a formula but the result I am getting is FALSE, when it should be returning a Lookup value, starting from the bottom of a table and going up.

```
Private Sub NewTaxCode()
Dim TaxCode2 As Long
Dim B As Range
Dim TaxCode3 As Range
Dim TaxCode4 As Range

Worksheets("P11Combined").Activate

Set B = Range("A:A")

Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("U1").Value = "=Match(RC[-4],P11Combined!C[-18],0)"
TaxCode2 = Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("U1").Value

Set TaxCode3 = Range("A:A").Find(What:="TAX:", After:=B(TaxCode2))

Set TaxCode4 = Range(TaxCode3.Address).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 2)

TaxCode5 = Range(TaxCode4.Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(R[-12]C:R[-1]C<>"" ""),(R[-12]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1]))"
```

The last line is where I am having the issues. The formula works fine on a spreadsheet but I can't get it to work in VBA.

Comment: *The formula works fine on a spreadsheet but I can't get it to work in VBA.* - record a macro of yourself entering the formula on a worksheet. The macro will record the correct syntax for you.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have tried but still can't figure it out.  This is the result I get, I think the roblem is when I change ActiveCell and then assigning it to another variable.   `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =  "=LOOKUP(2,1/(R[-13]C:R[-1]C<>"" ""),(R[-13]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1]))"`

Comment: what is `TaxCode4.Address` when it errors?

Comment: your comment is not clear and inconsistent with your question. And now that i re-read it there's no variable being used in the formula at all. Is the issue with the formula or `TaxCode4.Address`?

Comment: Apologies, still very new to this, but I have just found that when I change the code to `Range(TaxCode4.Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(R[-12]C:R[-1]C<>"" ""),(R[-12]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1]))"` I get the correct result placed in the cell address of TaxCode4. I suppose the question I'm asking is how to I assign that cell address that the value was found in during the lookup to a variable to further manipulate. Hope that makes sense

Comment: If you want to write to `TaxCode4` (a `Range` object), then write to `TaxCode4` - don't use its `Address` to fetch yet another reference to the very same object! `TaxCode4.FormulaR1C1 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code is of the format

```
variable = logical_expression
```

and is setting a variable (`TaxCode5`) to be either `True` or `False` depending on whether or not the formula in the cell referred to by `TaxCode4` is the same as the one in the code.

It does **not** modify the formula in the cell referred to by `TaxCode4`.

It appears you want:

```
Private Sub NewTaxCode()
    Dim TaxCode2 As Long
    Dim B As Range
    Dim TaxCode3 As Range
    Dim TaxCode4 As Range
    Dim TaxCode5 As Variant

    Set B = Worksheets("P11Combined").Range("A:A")

    Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("U1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Match(RC[-4],P11Combined!C[-18],0)"
    TaxCode2 = Worksheets("E'ee Details").Range("U1").Value

    Set TaxCode3 = B.Find(What:="TAX:", After:=B(TaxCode2))

    Set TaxCode4 = TaxCode3.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 2)

    TaxCode4.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(R[-12]C:R[-1]C<>"" ""),(R[-12]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1]))"
    TaxCode5 = TaxCode4.Value
    '...
End Sub
```